# How do I convert a double into a string in C++?

Tags: c++, string, double

I need to store a double as a string.  I know I  can use `printf` if I wanted to display it, but I just want to store it in a string variable so that I can store it in a map later (as the *value*, not the *key*).

Comment: A question to answer your question: why are you storing the double value in a string to store it in a map? Are you going to use the string-ified double as the key? If not, why not leave the double as is?

Comment: Interesting point.  Using a double as a map key may fraught with peril, however, as exact comparisons on floating point values always are.  Indexing on a string representation avoids the problem.

Comment: No, the double is going in as the value in a map<string, string>.  I have a bunch of configuration parameters that are of mixed types, and I'm using the map as a convenient place to store them all.

Comment: Why convert it at all?  Store it in the map as a double, and avoid the conversion to and from.

Comment: I'm storing strings in the map because I have multiple types to validate and store.

Comment: That still sounds like a call for objects.  A union would work.  Each the object to insert various values into it, and have it self validate.

Comment: I only have a bunch of name/value pairs in a file.  It doesn't call for objects.

Comment: Using a double as a key, no matter if with or without conversion to string, sounds like a design mistake. A double is fuzzy, but a key needs to be a unique identifier.

Comment: @Konstantin I wasn't using a double as a key.

Answer (score 198, accepted):

The *boost (tm)* way:

```
std::string str = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(dbl);
```

The *Standard C++* way:

```
std::ostringstream strs;
strs << dbl;
std::string str = strs.str();
```

**Note**: Don't forget `#include <sstream>`

Comment: I think boost::lexical_cast pretty much IS the standard C++ way, just nicely packaged for you.  BTW, litb, you have a minor typo in there -- "boot:lexical_cast".

Comment: boost::lexical_cast is not just a simple wrapper around the stringstream code. Many of the conversion routines are implemented inline. According to the performance measurements on the bottom of this page (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm), boost::lexical_cast is faster than using stringstreams and, in most cases, faster than scanf/printf

Comment: @Ferr who said it was a simple wrapper? And thanks for providing the link, I actually *did* think it was more or less a simple wrapper :)

Comment: don't forget to `#include <sstream>` for the c++ way :)

Comment: For the sake of documentation, if you don't `#include <sstream>`, you'll get an error "incomplete type is not allowed."

Comment: Will there be a data loss when using this?

Comment: @jeffrycopps Yes there will in the `ostringstream` version.  If you want to represent the double fully enough to round-trip you need to add something like `std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<double>::max_digits10)`

Answer (score 236):

```
// The C way:
char buffer[32];
snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%g", myDoubleVar);

// The C++03 way:
std::ostringstream sstream;
sstream << myDoubleVar;
std::string varAsString = sstream.str();

// The C++11 way:
std::string varAsString = std::to_string(myDoubleVar);

// The boost way:
std::string varAsString = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(myDoubleVar);
```

Comment: Upvoted for the C++ 11 way. I am new to C++, and didn't realize that there was a `to_string` function. I'm using Microsoft Visual C++ 2013.

Comment: Important note:
"std::to_string" has a precision of 6 digits. So the resulting string is basically a float and not a double.

Answer (score 148):

The *Standard C++11* way (if you don't care about the output format):

```
#include <string>

auto str = std::to_string(42.5);
```

[`to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) is a new library function introduced in [N1803](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1803.html) (r0), [N1982](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n1982.html) (r1) and [N2408](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2408.html) (r2) "*Simple Numeric Access*". There are also the `stod` function to perform the reverse operation.

If you do want to have a different output format than `"%f"`, use the `snprintf` or `ostringstream` methods as illustrated in other answers.

Comment: oh yeah baby. to_string and stod both work in Visual Studio 11.

Comment: Oh dear baby... to_string doesn't appear to work in VisualStudio 2010 ): That, or I don't know what I'm doing (very possible)

Comment: Is there any way to make this function not add more decimals than needed? When I convert the double `8.0` it gives me the string `"8.000000"`, while `"8"` would be perfectly fine.

Comment: you could just do something like `for(int lsd=str.len(); lsd>0 && str[lsd] == '0'; lsd--); str = str.substr(lsd);`

Comment: This doesn't work for small numbers... eg: `1e-9` produces `0.000000`

Answer (score 32):

You can use [**std::to_string**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) in C++11

```
double d = 3.0;
std::string str = std::to_string(d);
```

Comment: My numbers were really small, and `std::to_string()` simply returned 0.000000 and not in the scientific form.

Comment: @erfan how to overcome that issue?

Comment: @laughing one way would be to use `std::stringstream myStringStream` and then do `myStringStream << myDouble`. you can also use `std::setprecision(x)`

Comment: @erfan that is a good one, thanks. Any shorter than that?

Comment: how is this answer different from kennytm's?

Answer (score 24):

If you use C++, avoid `sprintf`. It's un-C++y and has several problems. Stringstreams are the method of choice, preferably encapsulated as in [Boost.LexicalCast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm) which can be done quite easily:

```
template <typename T>
std::string to_string(T const& value) {
    stringstream sstr;
    sstr << value;
    return sstr.str();
}
```

Usage:

```
string s = to_string(42.5);
```

Answer (score 11):

`sprintf` is okay, but in C++, the better, safer, and also slightly slower way of doing the conversion is with `stringstream`:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

// In some function:
double d = 453.23;
std::ostringstream os;
os << d;
std::string str = os.str();
```

You can also use [Boost.LexicalCast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm):

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <string>

// In some function:
double d = 453.23;
std::string str = boost::lexical_cast<string>(d);
```

In both instances, `str` should be `"453.23"` afterward. LexicalCast has some advantages in that it ensures the transformation is complete. It uses `stringstream`s internally.

Answer (score 9):

I would look at the [C++ String Toolkit Libary](http://www.partow.net/programming/strtk/index.html).  Just posted a similar answer elsewhere.  I have found it very fast and reliable.

```
#include <strtk.hpp>

double pi = M_PI;
std::string pi_as_string  = strtk::type_to_string<double>( pi );
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem with lexical_cast is the inability to define precision.  Normally if you are converting a double to a string, it is because you want to print it out.  If the precision is too much or too little, it would affect your output.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to convert a `double` into a string is via `std::to_string` but unfortunately it's pretty broken up to C++23 (e.g. it poorly handles small and large in magnitude numbers due to fixed format) although [it may be fixed in C++26](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2587r3.html).

Until `std::to_string` is fixed you can use C++20 [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format), e.g.

```
std::string s = std::format("{}", 0.42); // s == "0.42"
```

**Disclaimer**: I'm the author of C++20 `std::format`.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use [stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/).

Answer (score 3):

Heh, I just wrote this (unrelated to this question):

```
string temp = "";
stringstream outStream;
double ratio = (currentImage->width*1.0f)/currentImage->height;
outStream << " R: " << ratio;
temp = outStream.str();

/* rest of the code */
```

Answer (score 3):

Normaly for this operations you have to use the C default ecvt, fcvt or gcvt Functions:

```
/* gcvt example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main ()
{
  char buffer [20];
  gcvt (1365.249,6,buffer);
  puts (buffer);
  gcvt (1365.249,3,buffer);
  puts (buffer);
  return 0;
}

Output:
1365.25
1.37e+003
```

As a Function:

```
void double_to_char(double f,char * buffer){
  gcvt(f,10,buffer);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at `sprintf()` and family.

Comment: I mentioned printf because googling turned up a bunch of articles that say to convert from a double to a string you use printf.  They make the assumption that the only thing you could be doing is printing, which in my case is false.

Comment: why you vote -1? I think sprintf is good. @BilltheLizard, sprint prints something to a char * not screen. Someone answered c method still got a lot of vote.

Answer (score 2):

[You may want to read my prior posting on SO.  (Macro'ed version with a temporary ostringstream object.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303562/c-format-macro-inline-ostringstream#306053)

For the record:  In my own code, I favor snprintf().  With a char array on the local stack, it's not that inefficient.  (Well, maybe if you exceeded the array size and looped to do it twice...)

(I've also wrapped it via vsnprintf().  But that costs me some type checking.  Yelp if you want the code...)

Answer (score 1):

Note that a string is just a representation of the double and converting it back to double may not result in the same value.
Also note that the default string conversion may trim the conversion to a certain precision.
In the standard C++ way, you can control the precision as follows:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    std::ostringstream sout;
    sout << M_PI << '\n';
    sout << std::setprecision(99) << M_PI << '\n';
    sout << std::setprecision(3) << M_PI << '\n';
    sout << std::fixed; //now the setprecision() value will look at the decimal part only.
    sout << std::setprecision(3) << M_PI << '\n';
    std::cout << sout.str();
}
```

which will give you the output

```
3.14159                                                                                                                                                                            
3.141592653589793115997963468544185161590576171875                                                                                                                                 
3.14                                                                                                                                                                               
3.142
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try a more compact style:

```
std::string number_in_string;

double number_in_double;

std::ostringstream output;

number_in_string = (dynamic_cast< std::ostringstream*>(&(output << number_in_double <<

std::endl)))->str();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `to_string()`.
example :

```
#include <iostream>   
#include <string>  

using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    string pi = "pi is " + to_string(3.1415926);
    cout<< "pi = "<< pi << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

run it yourself : http://ideone.com/7ejfaU
These are available as well :

```
string to_string (int val);
string to_string (long val);
string to_string (long long val);
string to_string (unsigned val);
string to_string (unsigned long val);
string to_string (unsigned long long val);
string to_string (float val);
string to_string (double val);
string to_string (long double val);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert any thing to anything using this function:

```
template<class T = std::string, class U>
T to(U a) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    T ret;
    ss << a;
    ss >> ret;
    return ret;
};
```

usage :

```
std::string str = to(2.5);
double d = to<double>("2.5");
```

Answer (score 0):

C++17 has introduced:
[std::to_chars, std::to_chars_result - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/to_chars)

> ```cpp
> std::to_chars_result to_chars( char* first, char* last, float       value,
>                                std::chars_format fmt, int precision );
> std::to_chars_result to_chars( char* first, char* last, double      value,
>                                std::chars_format fmt, int precision );
> std::to_chars_result to_chars( char* first, char* last, long double value,
>                                std::chars_format fmt, int precision );
> ```

Which provide fast low level way to convert floating points into string with some level of format control. This should be fast since no allocation is done, only custom implementation for specific scenario should be faster.

C++20 has introduced high level easy to use format string (equivalent of fmt library):

[std::format - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format)

> std::format
>
> ```cpp
> template< class... Args >
> std::string format( /*format_string<Args...>*/ fmt, Args&&... args );
>
> template< class... Args >
> std::wstring format( /*wformat_string<Args...>*/ fmt, Args&&... args );
>
> template< class... Args >
> std::string format( const std::locale& loc,
>                     /*format_string<Args...>*/ fmt, Args&&... args );
>
> template< class... Args >
> std::wstring format( const std::locale& loc,
>                      /*wformat_string<Args...>*/ fmt, Args&&... args );
> ```

Which is quite nice and handy. Should be faster then `sprintf`.