# Check for Character instead of Integer

Tags: c

my program adds numbers entered by the user. It runs and works great until a character is entered instead of an integer. Is there a simple way to make sure only integers are entered from the keyboard?

Here is my code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   int n, sum = 0, i, TotalOfNumbers;

   printf("Enter the number of integers you want to add\n"); 
   scanf("%d", &n); 

   printf("Enter %d integers\n",n); 

   for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
   {
      scanf("%d",&TotalOfNumbers);
      sum = sum + TotalOfNumbers;
   }

   printf("Sum of entered integers = %d\n",sum); 

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023079/check-if-a-value-from-scanf-is-a-number

Comment: read the value in as a character string instead of an int, and then validate it.  Convert to int if valid.

Comment: Check ASCii value and get work done

Comment: Check the results of `scanf()` It will tell you how many requested parameters were *successfully* parsed. And since you're only requesting one.. well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the return value of `scanf`. If the input was a valid number, it will return 1. If the input was not a valid number, it will return something else. Here is your code modified to put the checks in.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int get_number()
{
   int num;
   int ret;

   ret = scanf("%d", &num);

   if (ret != 1) {
      printf("bad number\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   return num;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   int n, sum = 0, i, TotalOfNumbers;

   printf("Enter the number of integers you want to add\n"); 
   n = get_number();

   printf("Enter %d integers\n",n); 

   for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
   {
      TotalOfNumbers = get_number();
      sum = sum + TotalOfNumbers;
   }

   printf("Sum of entered integers = %d\n",sum); 

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer my question. Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Check the ferror state on the input stream

```
scanf("%d",&TotalOfNumbers);
if(!ferror(stdin)){
  sum = sum + TotalOfNumbers;
}
```

Comment: I won't downvote, but there is no `try..catch` construct in C.

Comment: Lol, i see now that i've messed up. Ill delete this and post a new solution for you ;) Your suposed to use ferror

Answer (score 1):

In addition to posted answer, there options not general as posted, but quicker.
First if you want to skip some final set of characters.In following example all letters,`!` and `+`  will be skiped

```
int n;
scanf("%*[a-zA-Z!+]%d",&n);
printf("\n%d",n);
```

for input

```
 weweqewqQQWWW!!!!+++3332
```

the output is

```
 3332
```

Next option is to use buffer wich allowed to read everything untill number is met, and then read the number. The disadvantage is that buffer size is limited

```
char buf[25];
int n;

scanf("%[^0-9]%d",buf,&n);
printf("\n%d",n);
```

For input

```
fgfuf@$@^^@^@@4565
```

Output

```
4565
```