# Is it possible to ignore certain characters in "scanf_s"?

Tags: c, character, scanf, letters

So here is my code. Its a school assignment. I had to make a program to calculate the square root of a number using a method the Babylonians developed etc, that's not the important part. What I was wondering is if it's possible to ignore letters in my `scanf` so that when I input a letter it doesn't go berserk in my terminal. Any help is welcome and greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

double root_Approach(double s); // defines the two functions 
void ask_Number(void);

int main() {

    ask_Number(); // calls function ask_Number

    printf("\n\n");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

double root_Approach(double s) {

    double approach;
    approach = s;
    printf("%.2lf\n", s);       // prints initial value of the number

    while (approach != sqrt(s)) {           // keeps doing iteration of this algorithm until the root is deterimened

        approach = (approach + (s / approach)) * 0.5;

        printf("%lf\n", approach);
    }

    printf("The squareroot of %.2lf is %.2lf\n",s, sqrt(s)); // prints the root using the sqrt command, for double checking purposes

    return approach;
}

void ask_Number(void) {

    double number;

    while (1) {
        printf("Input a number greater than or equal to 0: "); // asks for a number
        scanf_s("%lf", &number); // scans a number

        if (number < 0) {
            printf("That number was less than 0!!!!!!\n");
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }
    root_Approach(number);
}
```

Comment: Check `scanf_s`'s return value. If zero, print an error message (optional) and flush the input stream using `int c; while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4016721/3049655

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `Scanf` reads whatever may be the input from the terminal (character or integer)

One way you can do is to check the return statement of `scanf` whether the read input is integer or not an integer.

Here is the sample code

```
    int num;
    char term;
    if(scanf("%d%c", &num, &term) != 2 || term != '\n')
        printf("failure\n");
    else
        printf("valid integer followed by enter key\n");
```

`

> this link may be helpful
>   [Check if a value from scanf is a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023079/check-if-a-value-from-scanf-is-a-number)