# Is there a way how to check if input I have scanfed is a number? With IF function in C?

Tags: c, if-statement, scanf

I need to input 1 to 3 numbers with values between 3 to 69 only. So when I input something different from a number the program should fprintf on stderr "The input isn't number". But I cannot find a way how to code that. And I should use if function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int i=0;

while (scanf("%d", &i) == 1)
{
    
    if (i<3 || i>69)
    {
    fprintf(stderr,"Error: Input is too big or too small!");

    return 101;
    }
    if (ISNT A NUMBER)
    {
    fprintf(stderr,"Error: Input isnt a number!");

    return 100;
    }
}
 
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to check the result of scanf for that. As foretold in the documentation about how to use the scanf function.

Comment: If the input does not match your format string, the return value will not be 1, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a value from scanf is a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023079/check-if-a-value-from-scanf-is-a-number)

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456303/how-to-validate-input-using-scanf

Comment: [Take a look at the solution to this question and try to adapt it to your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072190/check-if-input-is-integer-type-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this correctly:

### Using scanf:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int get_num() {
    int i;

    printf("Enter a number between 3 and 69: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    if (scanf("%d", &i) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "incorrect number of arguments, we need exactly one number (between 3 and 69)\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if( i < 3 || i > 69 ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "oops the number must be between [3, 69]\n");
        return -2;
    }

    return i;
}

void eat_trash() {
    int c;
    while((c = getchar())!= '\n' && c !=EOF);
}

int main() {
    int value;
    while ((value = get_num()) <= 0 ) {
        eat_trash();
    }
    printf("Got: %d\n", value);
}
```

### A little extra but has interesting but (maybe slightly silly) things:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int stdin_copy;

int get_num() {
    int i, rv = 0;
    static int err_count = 0;
    char *input = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;

    printf("Enter a number between 3 and 69: ");
    fflush(stdout);

    // gets a line (allocates memory we have to free)
    rv = getline(&input, &len, stdin);

    if ( rv > 3  ) {
        err_count++; // see if we have a lot of garbage incoming
        free(input);

        if (err_count < 3 ) {
            fprintf(stderr, "a number between 3 and 9 only needs two characters, try again. (%d tries left)\n", 3 - err_count);
            return -3;
        }
        // just stop dealing with this silly user.
        fprintf(stderr, "really? okay bye!\n");
        exit(127);
    }

    rv = sscanf(input, "%d", &i);
    free(input);

    if (rv != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "incorrect number of arguments, we need exactly one number (between 3 and 69)\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if( i < 3 || i > 69 ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "oops the number must be between [3, 69]\n");
        return -2;
    }

    return i;
}

void eat_trash() {
    fclose(stdin);
    stdin = fdopen(stdin_copy, "r");
    stdin_copy = dup(fileno(stdin));
}


int main() {
    int value;
    stdin_copy = dup(0);
    while ((value = get_num()) <= 0 ) {
        eat_trash();
    }
    printf("Got: %d\n", value);
}
```

The thing to note is the way trash is being consumed. The trouble with this is what happens if user pushes an input without `\n` and then we are stuck in the way getline functions (also it can use up memory and that needing to free the input is annoying). So,

Comment: Corners, input like `"+12\n"`, `"003\n"` fails, yet accepts `"3x\n"`. A way out is to use `strtol()`, check for conversion success and then range.

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way how to check if input I have scanfed is a number? With IF function in C

The best is to read the user input *line* with `fgets()`, (or `getline()` if you have it) and *then* parse for an integer with `strtol()`.

The troubles with `scanf("%d", ...` include

- Leaving non-numeric input in `stdin`.
- Not reading the entire line.
- Reading multiple lines when first ones are all white-space.
- Not detecting trailing nun-numeric input.
- Undefined behavior on `int` overflow.

Instead read a *line* and form a *string*.  Then parse the string:

```
char *endptr;
long num = strtol(input_line_as_a_string, &endptr, 10);

if (input_line_as_a_string == endptr) {
  printf("No conversion happened. Input is non-numeric\n");
} else if (num < 3 || num > 69) {
  printf("Input %ld is out of range\n", num);
} else {
  while (isspace(*endptr)) endptr;  // skip trailing white-space
  if (*endptr != '\0') {
    printf("Input has trailing input\n");
  } else {
    printf("Success %ld\n", num);
  }
}
```