# scanf() curious behaviour!

Tags: c++, c, scanf

I recently stumbled upon a curious case(atleast for me, since I hadn't encountered this before)..Consider the simple code below:-

```
int x;
scanf("%d",&x);
printf("%d",x);
```

The above code takes a normal integer input and displays the result as expected..

Now, if I modify the above code to the following:-

```
int x;
scanf("%d ",&x);//notice the extra space after %d
printf("%d",x);
```

This takes in another additional input before it gives the result of the printf statement.. I don't understand why a space results in change of behaviour of the scanf().. Can anyone explain this to me....

Comment: scanf is EVIL and should be avoided - so say I, and others :) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456303/how-to-validate-input-using-scanf

Comment: @Bukes: yes, if you don't know how to program, or read documentation, you should not use C

Comment: @Chris Dodd - `scanf` can't distinguish between newlines and other whitespace. If you want fine control over your input, or the ability to sanely recover from errors, you can't use `scanf` regardless of how well you know C.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From http://beej.us/guide/bgc/output/html/multipage/scanf.html:

> The scanf() family of functions reads data from the console or from a FILE stream, parses it, and stores the results away in variables you provide in the argument list.
>
> The format string is very similar to that in printf() in that you can tell it to read a "%d", for instance for an int. **But it also has additional capabilities, most notably that it can eat up other characters in the input that you specify in the format string**.

What's happening is scanf is pattern matching the format string (kind of like a regular expression). scanf keeps consumes text from standard input (e.g. the console) until the entire pattern is matched.

In your second example, scanf reads in a number and stores it in x. But it has not yet reached the end of the format string -- there is still a space character left. So scanf reads additional whitespace character(s) from standard input in order to (try to) match it.

Answer (score 3):

From the [man page:](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?scanf)

> The format string consists of a sequence of directives  which  describe
>          how  to  process  the sequence of input characters.  If processing of a
>          directive fails, no further input is  read,  and  scanf()  returns.   A
>          "failure"  can  be either of the following: input failure, meaning that
>          input characters were unavailable, or matching  failure,  meaning  that
>          the input was inappropriate (see below).

```
   A directive is one of the following:

   ?      A  sequence of white-space characters (space, tab, newline, etc;
      see isspace(3)).  This directive matches  any  amount  of  white
      space, including none, in the input.
```

Comment: Note that this means that when there's a space in the format, scanf will read input. consuming and discarding whitespace characters until it finds a non-whitespace character.  It will leave that character as the next to be read and then return.

Answer (score 0):

`man scanf`

> [...] 
>      A sequence of white-space characters (space, tab, newline, etc.;
>      see isspace(3)).  This directive matches  any  amount  of  white
>      space, including none, in the input.

Comment: @Christian Rau: It is about pattern matching. A space `matches any amount of white space, [...], in the input`. Seems like an answer.