# scanf asking for two values instead of one

Tags: c, scanf

When I compile this code, it leads to scanf asking for a value twice when I pick choice A. What am I missing here?

This isn't the first time this is encountered, so I'm suspecting I'm failing to grasp something rather fundamental with scanf.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

char choice;
printf("1. 'enter 'A' for this choice\n");
printf("2. 'enter 'B' for this choice\n");
printf("3. 'enter 'C' for this choice\n");

scanf("%c", &choice);

switch (choice)
{
case 'A':
    {
        int a =0;
        printf("you've chosen menu A\n");
        printf("enter a number\n");
        scanf("%d\n", &a);
        printf("%d\n", a);
    }
break;
case 'B':
printf("you've chosen B\n");
break;
case 'C':
printf("you've chosen C\n");
break;
default:
printf("your choice is invalid\n!");
break;
}

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Unrelated,but shouldn't the `\n` in the `printf` in the `default` case be placed **after** the exclamation mark?

Answer (score 6):

`scanf("%d\n", &a);` should be `scanf("%d", &a);`

Also read [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349837/scanf-curious-behaviour).

In former case after reading an integer and storing into a, `scanf`'s argument string is not exhausted. Looking at `\n`, scanf would consume all the whitespaces (newline, tab, spaced etc) it sees (And will remain blocked) until it encounters a non-whitespace character. On encountering a non-whitespace character `scanf` would return.

**Learning:** Don't use space, newline etc as trailing character in scanf. If the space character is in the beginning of argument string, scanf may still skip any number of white space characters **including zero** characters. But when whitespace is a trailing characters, it would eat your new line character also unless you type a non-whitespace character and hit return key.

Comment: The space before `%c` is unecessary here.

Comment: @CoolGuy You are loosing nothing with that space. Read Related question 2. Moreover having the space would skip unwanted newline or space in the beginning.

Comment: Makes sense. But how does the unwanted newlines and/or spaces appear in the `stdin` in the beginning of the program?

Comment: @CoolGuy If you are redirecting a file or even using stdin, there may be unwanted space sometimes mistyped by mistake. Because there is almost no harm in using a whitespace in beginning while scanning a char, I suggested to use it but later remove it not to confuse the main point of the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Simply remove the newline character from `scanf("%d\n", &a);` and it will not ask to enter a value twice

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%d", &a);
```

Remove a newline character while scanning

Answer (score 0):

```
// the trailing '\n' in the scanf format string 
// is what is causing the dual inputs

// the returned value from I/O statements (I.E. scanf)
// needs to be checked to assure operation was successful

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    char choice;
    printf("1. 'enter 'A' for this choice\n");
    printf("2. 'enter 'B' for this choice\n");
    printf("3. 'enter 'C' for this choice\n");

    // note 
    //    leading ' ' in format string to consume leading white space 
    //    and no trailing '\n'
    if( 1 != scanf(" %c", &choice) ) 
    { // then, scanf failed
        // handle error condition
        perror("scanf failed for choice");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // implied else, scanf successful

    switch (choice)
    {
        case 'A':
        { // braces needed due to variable declaration
            int a = 0; // corrected ':' to ';'
            printf("you've chosen menu A\n");
            printf("enter a number\n");

            // note 
            //    leading ' ' in format string to consume leading white space 
            //    and no trailing '\n'
            if( 1 != scanf(" %d", &a) ) 
            { // then scanf failed
                // handle error condition
                perror("scanf failed for number");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            // implied else, scanf successful
            printf("%d\n", a);
        }
        break;

        case 'B':
            printf("you've chosen B\n");
        break;

        case 'C':
            printf("you've chosen C\n");
        break;

        default:
            printf("your choice is invalid\n!");
        break;
    } // end switch

    return 0;

} // end function: main
```