# c while loop treats local variable in loop as global, why?

Tags: c, memory, while-loop

below is a small C application. It will ask you for a word to input. It stops asking when has attained four unique words. But in the form shown below it won't run properly until you uncomment the relevant lines.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define WORDS_COUNT 4

int main()
{
    char* words[WORDS_COUNT];

    int words_added = 0;
    while (words_added<WORDS_COUNT)
    {

        puts ("\n-------enter a word-------");

        char response[250];

        scanf("%s", response);

        int i;
        int duplicate_flag = 0;
        for (i=0; i < words_added; i++)
        {
            if (strcmp(words[i], response) == 0)
            {
                duplicate_flag = 1;
                break;
            };
        };

        if (duplicate_flag == 0)
        {
            //char tmp[250];
            //strcpy(tmp, response);
            words[words_added] = response; //words[words_added] = tmp;
            puts("that's new!");
            words_added ++;
        } else {
            puts("you've said that already...");
        };

    };
    return 0;
};
```

The major difference as you can see is between `words[words_added] = response` and `words[words_added] = tmp`.

Why would the `tmp` variable work and not the `response`?

I'm guessing that `response` will have the exact same address every iteration, and `tmp` will get a new address every iteration. but why? yet they were both declared in same the while loop???

Comment: You code is badly broken and exhibiting undefined behavior. Your problem is that you have not allocated any permanent storage for the list of existing words--only of the pointers to them.

Comment: [you seriously not want your program to be an entry point for buffer overflow exploitation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/456312/1025391)!

Comment: @moooeeeep that would be a little paranoid here, it's just a little example code snippet, but point taken ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you assign `words[words_added] = response` you're copying the address (not the contents) of `response` into the array.  So in the original form, your code should see the second word and every subsequent word as duplicates.  When you use `tmp` the code compares each new `response` to the previous `tmp` that was stored in (every location  of) `words[]`, then copies it into `tmp` if it's not a duplicate.

So I suspect that your code will detect a duplicate that *immediately* follows the original, but not one that occurs 2 or more words later.

The `words` array contains 4 pointers, but no memory has been allocated to those pointers.
You need to allocate memory for each element of the `words` array, and then copy each string into it:

```
if (duplicate_flag == 0)
{
  words[words_added++] = strdup(response); // allocates mem and copies the string
  puts("that's new!");
} else {
  ...
}
```

Then be sure to `free` the memory at the end of your program:

```
for (i = 0; i < words_added; ++i) {
  free(words[i]);
}
```

Comment: "The tmp variable is allocated on the stack each time through the for loop, while response persists for the live of the program" yes but why does `tmp` get allocated and not `response`?

Comment: You're absolutely right--good catch!  I've revised my answer, and I think I've explained the behavior more accurately.  Would you mind testing my suspicion that only immediate duplicates will be caught?  If you can confirm that, I'm confident we understand what's happening.

Comment: CONFIRMED! I can see exactly what you mean, there was no "re-allocation" but instead my code was only comparing `response` to the last "different" `response` that was copied into temp!. Why have I always assumed that re-allocations occur within loops? SMH. thanks!

Comment: Since those variables are allocated on the stack I wouldn't be surprised if they were deallocated and reallocated during each iteration, but they'd likely end up in the same memory locations.  Moreover, they'd probably be unchanged between iterations--but only by "accident" because the code doesn't happen to overwrite the memory between iterations.  If you're serious about catching memory-related bugs, you can `memset` variables to zeroes (or invalid, easily-recognized values like `0xAA`) before you release them, to force errors to manifest faster.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it wrong - you're pointing an array of pointers - `words[words_added]` - at a variable that changes on every iteration - `response`

You need to allocate storage for `words[words_added]` on each iteration, before you strcpy:
 `strcpy(words[words_added], response);`

P.S. Don't put semi-colons after closing braces `}`

Comment: tmp and response are of the same type. so isn't tmp also changing every iteration?

Comment: doesn't matter - it might have worked - but that was an anomaly - do the appropriate memory allocation `malloc` (and don't forget to deallocate `free` when done)

Comment: in the real program that's exactly what I've done, but I really want to understand why the compiler was giving `response` the special treatment. All other local variables in a while loop always get re-allocated, never seen a variable behave like `response` is doing. I really want to know why.

Comment: @codeshogan see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6445794/1025391) and simply accept that you shouldn't do such thing.

Comment: @moooeeeep Sometimes I like to be sneaky, when things fall apart and you examine what went wrong you learn more about how it all works. I was hoping to exploit the effect described in you link to see if I could get this (actually a similar) algorithm running entirely on stack...

Comment: @codeshogan why don't you use a `char words[NUM_WORDS][MAX_WORD_LENGTH];` then?

Comment: @moooeeeep I figured if I started to subscript strings and looping through them I would in effect be re-inventing the `string.h` wheel.

Comment: @moooeeeep i also just found `alloca`, which does exactly what I wanted to do, BUT it has been pointed out that even if I were able to use it I would then run the risk of stack overflows. Safe to say I'm done with my experimenting, I know what not to do, and learnt about `alloca` on the way! (but wouldn't use `alloca` for this sort of situation, malloc/calloc instead).