# What does the n stand for in `sscanf(s, "%d %n", &i, &n)`?

Tags: c

The man page states that the signature of `sscanf` is

```
sscanf(const char *restrict s, const char *restrict format, ...);
```

I have seen an [answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/456314/641514) where a function in which `sscanf` is used like this to check if an input was an integer.

```
bool is_int(char const* s) {
    int n;
    int i;
    return sscanf(s, "%d %n", &i, &n) == 1 && !s[n];
}
```

Looking at `!s[n]` it seems to suggest that we check if `sscanf` scanned the character sequence until the termination character `\0`. So I assume `n` stands for the index where sscanf will be in the string `s` when the function ends.

**But what about the variable `i`? What does it mean?**

**Edit:**

To be more explicit: I see the signature of `sscanf` wants a pointer of type `char *` as first parameter. A format specifier as seconf parameter so it knows how to parse the character sequence and as much variables as conversion specifiers as next parameters. I understand now that `i` is for holding the parsed integer.

Since there is  only one format specifier, I tried to deduce the function of `n`.

Is my assumption above for `n` correct?

Comment: It's the `int` variable `sscanf` stores the parsed value in.

Comment: Address (`&`) of an **integer** (`i`).

Comment: read further down the manpage.

Comment: The `i` means iNeedABetterName

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like the op has his answer already, but since I bothered to look this up for myself and run the code...

From "C The Pocket Reference" (2nd Ed by Herbert Shildt) scanf() section:

> %n Receives an integer of value equal to the number of characters read so far

and for the return value:

> The scanf() function returns a number equal to the number of the number of fields
>   that were successfully assigned values

The sscanf() function works the same, it just takes it's input from the supplied buffer argument ( s in this case ).  The "== 1" test makes sure that only one integer was parsed and the !s[n] makes sure the input buffer is well terminated after the parsed integer and/or that there's really only one integer in the string.

Running this code, an s value like "32" gives a "true" value ( we don't have bool defined as a type on our system ) but s as "3 2" gives a "false" value because s[n] in that case is "2" and n has the value 2 ( "3 " is parsed to create the int in that case ).  If s is " 3 " this function will still return true as all that white space is ingored and n has the value of 3.

Another example input, "3m", gives a "false" value as you'd expect.

Comment: I assume it is allowed to switch an already good answer by a more detailed one so other people running into the same question find the answer faster. Thanks a lot for your effort, mate!

Answer (score 6):

Verbatim from `sscanf()`'s man page:

> Conversions
>
> [...]
>
> n
>
> Nothing is expected; instead, the number of characters
>   consumed thus far from the input is stored through the next pointer,
>   which must be a pointer to int.  This is not a
>   conversion, although it can be suppressed with the * assignment-suppression character.  The C 
>   standard says: "Execution of
>   a %n directive does not increment  the  assignment  count  returned  at  the completion of 
>   execution" but the Corrigendum seems to contradict this.  Probably it is wise not
>   to make any assumptions on the effect of %n conversions on the return value.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed. Now that you point the relevant position out I understand what was meant.

Comment: Yeah, it is a lot to consume - especially for a beginner who is new to the concept of c. :-)

Comment: I switched the Answers because of a more detailled one, no offense. Simply trying to make sure other people with the same question can find the best answer faster. But I am not less thankful then before and you already got my +1. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to point out that the original code is buggy:

```
bool is_int(char const* s) {
    int n;
    int i;
    return sscanf(s, "%d %n", &i, &n) == 1 && !s[n];
}
```

I will explain why. And I will interpret the sscanf format string.

First, buggy:

Given input "1", which is the integer one, sscanf will store 1 into i. Then, since there is no white space after, sscanf will not touch n. And n is uninitialized. Because sscanf set i to 1, the value returned by sscanf will be 1, meaning 1 field scanned. Since sscanf returns 1, the part of the expression

```
sscanf(s, "%d %n", &i, &n) == 1
```

will be true. Therefore the other part of the && expression will execute. And s[n] will access some random place in memory because n is uninitialized.

Interpreting the format:

```
"%d %n"
```

Attempts to scan a number which may be a decimal number or an integer or a scientific notation number. The number is an integer, it must be followed by at least one white space. White space would be a space, \n, \t, and certain other non-printable characters. Only if it is followed by white space will it set n to the number of characters scanned to that point, including the white space.

This code might be what is intended:

```
    static bool is_int(char const* s) 
    {
        int i;
        int fld;
        return (fld = sscanf(s, "%i", &i)) == 1;
    }

    int main(int argc, char * argv[])
    {
        bool ans = false;

        ans = is_int("1");
        ans = is_int("m");

        return 0;
    }
```

This code is based on, if s is an integer, then sscanf will scan it and fld will be exactly one. If s is not an integer, then fld will be zero or -1. Zero if something else is there, like a word; and -1 if nothing is there but an empty string.

Comment: Correction: The above code should use %d instead of %i. I had the two confused.

Comment: The affirmation `since there is no white space after, sscanf will not touch n.` **is not completely right**. The format `"%d %n"` **doesn't impose** an whitespace, it **actually permits** it, which may still be a problem if you need a strict validation. Using `"%d %n"` to parse `"123 "` (with a trailing space) would make it pass the test, while `%d%n` would not.

Answer (score 0):

variable `i` there means until it has read an integer vaalue.

what are you trying to ask though? Its not too clear! the code will (try to ) read an integer from the string into 'i'