# Cast a pointer to char to a double C++

Tags: c++

How can i cast a pointer to char to a double ?
I am using command line arguments and one of the argument is a double but in the program is it passed as a char*.
I tried using static_cast and reinterpret_cast but with no effect.

Comment: Duplicate of [How can I convert string to double in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392981/how-can-i-convert-string-to-double-in-c)

Comment: Just a note. You're not really interested in casting a char * to a double. You want to convert a c string representation of a double to a double. Casting a char * to a double would literally just be taking the address of a character and turning that into a numeric representation stored in a double.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pure C++ solution:

```
#include <sstream>

// ...

std::stringstream ss;
ss << your_char_pointer;
ss >> your_double;
```

Boost solution:

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

// ...

your_double = boost::lexical_cast<double>(your_char_pointer);
```

Comment: Both probably involve an unnecessary copy of the string; I'd rather use `std::atof()` (or `std::strtod()` if you need to report errors).

Answer (score 3):

Try [Boost lexical_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm).

Answer (score 3):

`double val = atof(*charpointer)`

atof stands for "all to float", (or "array to float"), and does exactly what you want. If it cannot convert the char array, it returns 0.0. See: [Man atof](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atof/)

Comment: I always thought it was "ASCII to float". Not that the system character set is necessarily ASCII, I just assumed it was named by someone who invented it for a system where it was. Any records one way or another?

Comment: @Steve Hmm I do indeed find more references for ASCII. Interesting, I was pretty sure that it was one of the aforementioned two. Well, thanks for correcting me in that case :) (although the most reliable source thus far is wikipedia)

Comment: Indeed, I'm not certain, and that Wikipedia page might have been written by someone like me, to whom it had never occurred that it might stand for anything else.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how type conversion in C/C++ works. You must pass the string through a numeric parser manually. E.g.

```
char *thestring;
double d;
d = atof(thestring);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the double comes from the command line, it is actually a real string, you have to convert it to a double, you can't just cast it.

For example, you can use [strtod](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtod/) for this task :

```
double d = strtod (mystr,NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to convert a string (represented by the `char *`) into a `double`. This is not something you can do with a regular built in type cast in C++ as all they do is reinterpret the bit pattern that is being referenced by the pointer. Instead you have to parse the command line argument to extract a double value from the string.

As mentioned, you have several options:

- you can use `atof` for the conversion, but it's hard to determine if the conversion errored because both a string that can't be converted and one representing 0.0 give you the same result
- As Fred Larson mentioned, you can use `boost::lexical_cast`. That's a pretty elegant way to handle the problem and would most likely be my preferred one
- You can use iostreams to do the conversion
- You can write the conversion code yourself (just kidding)

Answer (score 0):

The `atof` man page says "The atof() function has been deprecated by strtod() and should not be used in new code."