# How check a double overflow when I tried to convert a char* to a double in c++

Tags: c++, string, casting, double

I want to convert a char * to a double in c++. But before do that, I want to check that the char * is a right double number. So I have made this code :

```
bool                    Tools::m_CheckIfDouble(char *p_nb)
{
    if (p_nb == NULL)
        return (false);
    for (unsigned int v_i = 0; p_nb[v_i]; v_i++)
        if ((p_nb[v_i] < '0' || p_nb[v_i] > '9') && (p_nb[v_i] != '.' && p_nb[v_i] != '-'))
            return (false);
    return (true);
}
```

but I don't know how to check the char * for a double overflow (if the value of the char * is greater than the value of DBL_MAX or lesser than DBL_MIX).

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392981/how-can-i-convert-string-to-double-in-c

Comment: I'd say use boost::lexical_cast unless you have a very good reason not to use it.

Comment: does this function manage error like double overflow or int overflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard library function `strtod` should do the trick:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cerrno>

double convert(char const * str)
{
    char * e;
    double res = std::strtod(str, &e);

    if (e == str || *e != 0) { /* error (invalid string) */ }

    if ((res == HUGE_VAL || -res == HUGE_VAL) && errno == ERANGE) { /* overflow */ }

    if (res == 0 && errno == ERANGE) { /* underflow */ }

    return res;
}
```

You get the idea; you can customize the error handling to your own requirements.

Comment: @AJG85: That would not only defeat the purpose of having sensible error checking, but `strtod` is part of C89 and C++98, so it's always been in both standards.

Comment: Ah yes so it is. It just looks like one of the new C++11 functions as @aelnajjar pointed out.