# What's the fastest way to check if a string is a number?

Tags: c++

What's the fastest way to check that a string like "2.4393" or "2" is valid- they can both be represented by a double- whilst the strings "2.343." or "ab.34" are not?  In particular, I want to be able to read any string and, if it *can* be a double, assign a double variable to it, and if it can't be a double (in the case that it's a word or just invalid input), an error message is displayed.

Comment: What is your input encoding? Simple ASCII or something else?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392981/how-can-i-convert-string-to-double-in-c might help.

Comment: put it in a stream (e.g. `std::stringstream`) and do `if ( !(stream >> mydouble) ) { myError(); }`.

Comment: @stefan: Won't that accept things like "3z" or "1.1."?

Comment: If I use atof(string) will that work as well?

Comment: If you just want to read double from a string( like reading "123.34ab" as "123.45"), it should be fine to use stringstream. If not, try a regex expression.

Comment: "123.34ab" should be invalid.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: You're right, my apologies. To avoid that, a simple check if the stream is empty should suffice.

Comment: To make sure there's no leftover cruft at the end (as noticed by @DavidSchwartz), you could try doing `char dummy; if (stream >> dummy) myError();` after successfully reading a `double`.  That will try to read a character, after first skipping any whitespace, which it should fail (EOF) iff the string is valid.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: What about `"2 "`? The question doesn't say whether it's valid, the answers below consider it invalid but your code considers it valid because it skips the whitespace and then fails to read a char.

Comment: @SteveJessop: The suggested `stringstream` approach already allows whitespace at the start, so I thought it makes sense to allow it at the end. But you're right -- the question itself doesn't say, so we should probably assume whitespace at either end is forbidden.  OP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) and confirm all data was consumed using [`eof()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/eof):

```
std::istringstream in("123.34ab");
double val;
if (in >> val && in.eof())
{
    // Valid, with no trailing data.
}
else
{
    // Invalid.
}
```

See demo at http://ideone.com/gpPvu8.

Comment: `in.eof()` would work too, wouldn't it?  (That would make it more "C++ stylish" @billybob)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [std::stod()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof). If the string can not be converted, an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned by stefan, you can use `std::istringstream`

```
coords          getWinSize(const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2)
{
  coords winSize;
  std::istringstream iss1(s1);
  std::istringstream iss2(s2);

  if ((iss1 >> winSize.x).fail())
    throw blabla_exception(__FUNCTION__, __LINE__, "Invalid width value");
  /*
   .....
  */
}
```

in my code, coords is :

```
typedef struct coords {
    int     x;
    int     y;
} coords;
```

Comment: it will not check  "123.45ab"

Answer (score 0):

Use [`boost::lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html), which throws an exception if conversion fails.