# An issue with GetDlgItemInt and SetDlgItemInt

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

Please observe the following code:

`double rate=GetDlgItemInt(IDC_EDIT1,0,TRUE);
    double term=GetDlgItemInt(IDC_EDIT2,0,TRUE);
    double amount=GetDlgItemInt(IDC_EDIT3,0,TRUE);
    double final;`

```
CString Content(_T("Thanks for using the calculator"));
if (CTaskDialog::IsSupported())
{
CString Heading(_T("Successfully calculated"));
CString Title(_T("Interest Calculator"));
CString Collapsed(_T("Collapsed Info"));
CString Expanded(_T("Expanded Info"));
CString Information(_T("Your information you want to calculate"));
CTaskDialog dia(Content,Heading,Title,TDCBF_OK_BUTTON);

final=amount*pow((1+rate),term);
SetDlgItemInt(IDC_EDIT4,final,FALSE);
dia.SetMainIcon(TD_ERROR_ICON);
dia.DoModal();
}
```

}

What I have tried to do is to create a GUI for a calculator which calculates the future value of a fund. I want to have all the variables as doubles. But the part of the code "GetDlgItemInt" is clearly meant for integers and I do not know how to alter it to get a double. Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `GetDlgItemText()` function and than convert received text to a double.

Comment: @VasilyBiryukov How can I convert it the text to double?

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392981/how-can-i-convert-string-to-double-in-c) SO question.

Answer (score 1):

An equivalent function that returns a `double` could be:

```
double GetDlgItemDouble(HWND hWnd, UINT uId)
{
    TCHAR tchBuf[80];
    GetDlgItemText(hWnd, uId, tchBuf, 80);
    return _ttof(tchBuf);
}
```

You may want to add error checking in case the string contains non-numeric characters, etc.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Isn't it better storing those values as CTaskDialog members?</strike>

(Sorry forgot what G(S)etDlgItem did)

You can do

```
float myFloat = 3.2;

CString text;
text.Format( L"%f", myFloat );

SetDlgItemText( yourID, text );
```