# Convert double to string C++?

Tags: c++, string, double, tostring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I convert a double into a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332111/how-do-i-convert-a-double-into-a-string-in-c)

I want to combine a string and a double and g++ is throwing this error:

main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:40: error: invalid operands of types ‘const char [2]’ and ‘double’ to binary ‘operator+’

Here is the line of code which it is throwing the error on:

```
storedCorrect[count] = "("+c1+","+c2+")";
```

storedCorrect[] is a string array, and c1 and c2 are both doubles. Is there a way to convert c1 and c2 to strings to allow my program to compile correctly?

Comment: How about some of the examples from the following: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/Tokenizer.aspx   They are very efficient and somewhat elegant.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29200635/395461

Answer (score 72):

You can't do it directly.  There are a number of ways to do it:

1. Use a [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream):

   ```
   std::ostringstream s;
   s << "(" << c1 << ", " << c2 << ")";
   storedCorrect[count] = s.str()
   ```
2. Use [`boost::lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm):

   ```
   storedCorrect[count] = "(" + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(c1) + ", " + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(c2) + ")";
   ```
3. Use [`std::snprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/snprintf):

   ```
   char buffer[256];  // make sure this is big enough!!!
   snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "(%g, %g)", c1, c2);
   storedCorrect[count] = buffer;
   ```

There are a number of other ways, using various double-to-string conversion functions, but these are the main ways you'll see it done.

Comment: I know this answer is old, but you might also want to include `std::string to_string( double );` here.

Answer (score 27):

In C++11, [use `std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) if you can accept the default format (`%f`).

```
storedCorrect[count]= "(" + std::to_string(c1) + ", " + std::to_string(c2) + ")";
```

Answer (score 23):

Use [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream).  Its `operator <<` is overloaded for all built-in types.

```
#include <sstream>    

std::stringstream s;
s << "(" << c1 << "," << c2 << ")";
storedCorrect[count] = s.str();
```

This works like you'd expect - the same way you print to the screen with `std::cout`.  You're simply "printing" to a string instead.  The internals of `operator <<` take care of making sure there's enough space and doing any necessary conversions (e.g., `double` to `string`).

Also, if you have the Boost library available, you might consider looking into [`lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm).  The syntax looks much like the normal C++-style casts:

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
using namespace boost;

storedCorrect[count] = "(" + lexical_cast<std::string>(c1) +
                       "," + lexical_cast<std::string>(c2) + ")";
```

Under the hood, `boost::lexical_cast` is basically doing the same thing we did with `std::stringstream`.  A key advantage to using the Boost library is you can go the other way (e.g., `string` to `double`) just as easily.  No more messing with `atof()` or `strtod()` and raw C-style strings.

Comment: Actually, `boost::lexical_cast` does not use `std::stringstream` under  the hood. It implements its own conversion routines which are significantly faster than the using `stringstream` and in most cases are faster than `scanf`/`printf`. See: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/performance.html

Comment: The source for `lexical_cast` looks much different from when I last saw it.  It appears they've improved performance considerably in the past couple of Boost releases.  That's even more reason to go with it if you can.

Answer (score 10):

```
std::string stringify(double x)
 {
   std::ostringstream o;
   if (!(o << x))
     throw BadConversion("stringify(double)");
   return o.str();
 }
```

C++ FAQ:
http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/misc-technical-issues.html#faq-39.1

Answer (score 1):

I believe the sprintf is the right function for you. I's in the standard library, like printf. Follow the link below for more information:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/

Comment: `sprintf` is unsafe for number formatting, because it doesn't do any bounds checking on the output buffer, and there's no good portable way to determine the size of the buffer that would be safe for any `double` value.

Comment: Well in that case, use `snprintf` :) But indeed, predicting the needed buffer size can be hard.