# how to convert a float number(1.00) to std::string C++

Tags: c++, floating-point

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert double to string C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123201/convert-double-to-string-c)

however, thanks everyone, I have a float number:1.000, how to convert it to a std::string ,like "1.000".

Answer (score 1):

```
std::stringstream stream;
float f = 1.000f;
stream << f;
std::string str;
stream >> str;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `stringstream`:

```
float val = 1.000f;
stringstream ss;
ss << val;
string stringVal = ss.str();
```

or use `boost::lexical_cast<>()` (which also uses stringstream underneath)

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
float val = 1.000f;
string stringVal = boost::lexical_cast<string>( val );
```

Comment: HeHe,thanks,but it is not work in my computer,I have tried sstream and boost.It is useless.It output 1.at last,thanks for help me.