# FPS Counter in the window title GLFW

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I'm trying to get my Frames-Per-Second readout to appear in my window title. I have done it once before, but how would I set up the code to do that?  I need to switch from float to const char *.

Comment: Converting float/double to string is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123201/convert-double-to-string-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way to do, and making it compatible with every numerical could be that:

```
#include <sstream>

template<class T>
char* toChar(T t) {
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << t;
    return oss.str().c_str();
}
```

This way, no matter if you use int, float, long or whatever else, it will work and return it as a char* string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [`istringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istringstream/) then `str()` then `c_str()`.