# C++ converting string to double using atof

Tags: c++, string, double, atof

I cannot get the `atof()` function to work. I only want the user to input values (in the form of decimal numbers) until they enter `'|'` and it to then break out the loop. I want the values to initially be read in as strings and then converted to doubles because I found in the past when I used this method of input, if you input the number '124' it breaks out of the loop because '124' is the code for the '|' char.

I looked around and found out about the `atof()` function which apparently converts `string`s to `double`s, however when I try to convert I get the message

> "no suitable conversion function from std::string to const char exists".

And I cannot seem to figure why this is.

```
void distance_vector(){

double total = 0.0;
double mean = 0.0;
string input = " ";
double conversion = 0.0;
vector <double> a;

while (cin >> input && input.compare("|") != 0 ){
conversion = atof(input);
a.push_back(conversion);
}

keep_window_open();
}
```

Comment: Now that I have answered and received experience, it now makes sense for me to find the duplicate question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754011/c-string-to-double-conversion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need

```
atof(input.c_str());
```

That would be the "suitable conversion function" in question.

`std::string::c_str` [Documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/):

> const char* c_str() const;
>   **Get C string equivalent**
>   Returns a pointer to an array that contains a null-terminated sequence of characters (i.e., a C-string) representing the current value of the string object.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the `strtod` function to convert a string to a double:

```
std::string param;  // gets a value from somewhere
double num = strtod(param.c_str(), NULL);
```

You can look up the documentation for `strtod` (e.g. `man strtod` if you're using Linux / Unix) to see more details about this function.