# jsoncpp: convert string to double

Tags: c++, json, c++11, type-conversion, jsoncpp

I am trying to take a string, that I know represents a decimal, from a JSON object and assign it to a double in C++.

One would expect that `asDouble()` does the job, but this is not the case. For example if we have the array `["0.4983", "4387"]` sitting in a variable `Json::Value arr`, doing

```
double x = arr[0].asDouble()
```

throws an exception `Value is not convertible to double.`

What is the recommended way of doing this (in C++ 11)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ string to double conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754011/c-string-to-double-conversion)

Comment: What happens when you try like this: `Json::Value val = arr[0]; double x = val.asDouble();`

Comment: what is the return value of `arr.isArray()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that `"0.4983"` is a string, so jsoncpp refuses to convert it into a double. This is reasonable since normally to convert a string such as `"abc"` into a double makes no sense.

What you need is to manually convert the string to double; in C++11 it would be [stod](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stod/).

Comment: This is actually what I'm doing at the moment. As far as I know - please correct me if I'm mistaken - Json does not support floating point numbers, only integers. So any decimal in Json would have to be represented by a string, i.e. enclosed by double quotation marks. Given how common it is to pass decimals in a Json objects, I feel jsoncpp should provide a function to convert strings to doubles that throws an exception if no conversion is possible. After all, this is exactly what one would do when first reading into a `std::string` and then trying to convert to double with `std::stod`.

Comment: Json do support floating point numbers; see http://json.org/, and I believe a modern library of json will support it. But ``["4.5"]`` is an array of string, while ``[4.5]`` is an array of floating point numbers.

Comment: So basically it's bad form to put floating point numbers packaged as strings in a Json. Can only hope that the data provider will change this at some point, and have to go with conversion via `std::stod` until then. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Just have a look at the source: https://github.com/oftc/jsoncpp/blob/master/src/lib_json/json_value.cpp#L852

Obviously in `jsoncpp` only `int`, `uint`, `real`, `null` and `boolean` could be coerced to `double`. `string` is not in the list.

There are many answers here at stackoverflow exmplaining how to do string->double conversion yourself. One of them: [C++ string to double conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754011/c-string-to-double-conversion)

Additionally there is `Value::isConvertibleTo()` which allows you to find at runtime if a value is convertible to a type: https://github.com/oftc/jsoncpp/blob/master/src/lib_json/json_value.cpp#L924