# How to apply arithmetic operation on strings in C++?

Tags: c++

I want to create a program that reads a string containing two numbers and a operator and prints out the results. It is continuously showing error on arithmetic operators. For instance, how would I add two strings together?

```
int main()
{
    string number1;
    string number2;
    string operation;
    string answer;

    cout << "Enter numbers with respective operations";
    cout << "number 1";
    cin >> number1; 
    cout << "number2";
    cin >> number2;
    cout << "operation";
    cin >> operation;
    if (operation == "+")
    {
        answer = number1 + number2;
        cout << "the sum is   " << answer << endl;
    }
    else if (operation == "-")
    {
        answer = number1 - number2;
        cout << "the difference is   " << answer << endl;
    }
    else if (operation == "*")
    {
        answer = number1 * number2;
        cout << "the product is   " << answer << endl;
    }
    else if (operation == "/")
    {
        answer = number1 / number2;
        cout << "the answer is   " << answer << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "invalid input" << endl;
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting the result of a `string` divided by a `string` to be??

Comment: what are the errors?

Comment: according to your code there is no reason for the numbers to be strings, why are they ?
  since they are strings you need to cast them to numbers if you want to calculate with them.

Comment: why do you use `string`s when you want `double`s ?

Comment: You have to first [convert the string to a numeric type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290089/how-to-convert-a-number-to-string-and-vice-versa-in-c) and then do the calculations on that value.

Comment: Could be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you _actually_ trying to do?

Comment: @xyious -- you can't **cast** a string to a number; you can **convert** it. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To help people answer your question, you'll need to be more specific about the error.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the exact errors you get from your [mcve] (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Comment: This question is unclear because, among other things, you do not provide an explanation for your choice to read in strings instead of some kind of data type which can actually be used for calculation/arithmetic.

Comment: I am creating a program that reads a string containing two numbers and a operator and print out the results

Answer (score 5):

You need to change the input types to numeric types, so you read actual numbers, not their string representations. As you can see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/), the only one of those operators that `string` overloads is `+` - and that's for concatenation of strings.

Changing...

```
string number1;
string number2;
string answer;
```

...to...

```
double number1;
double number2;
double answer;
```

...should fix your issue.

Alternatively you can read strings as you do now then convert them to numbers (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194465/how-to-parse-a-string-to-an-int-in-c)), but that's just adding more work when you don't need it. **Unless** you want to detect invalid numeric values (like `1234abc8`), in which case reading a string then parsing and checking for invalid input is a good idea.

Comment: yeah I am always 1 second late, but eventually I gave up to update my comments ;)

Comment: I can do it by changing string into double data type. But this is an assignment question that taking two operand and one operator via string and perform basic calculating operation.

Comment: @Sumair Then take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754011/c-string-to-double-conversion), to do the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Both `number1` and `number2` in your example are strings, which do not support adding values together. You could simply switch the types of `number1` and `number2` as well as `answer` to ints:

```
int main()
{
    float number1;
    float number2;
    string operation; // could switch this to char too
    float answer;
    // ...
```

If you really want to use strings you could use stringstreams contained in `<sstream>` :
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/stringstream/

Edit1: `float` might be the better type if you care about post floating point values.

Comment: `int`s will probably not produce the results that OP wants for division

Comment: basically this is my assignment question in which I am facing difficulty. The question is.  create a program that reads a string containing two numbers and a operator and print out the results. The string are to be interpreted by your programme.

Comment: In that case, you will need to use stringstreams.