# problems with text files in C ++

Tags: c++, file, text, fstream

They ask us to implement a function that reads from the second line of text file CSV as follows:

> **PRE:** The flow «f» is associated with a text file with the format of uses
>    of the Bizi system established in the statement and in the disposition of
>    read from the beginning of a line other than the header.
>    **Post:** You have tried to read the line mentioned in the precondition and, if you 
>    have not finished the data of the file in that attempt, you have stored in the 
>    fields of the parameter "use" the user's identifier to which corresponds the use 
>    of the read line and the codes of the bicycle removal and return stations.

```
void leerUso(istream& f, UsoBizi& uso) {}
```

Please can some one help me to understand *How I can read from second line of text file that separate by (;) and extract parameter, with example?*

Comment: read the first line, the next line you read is the second line ;). Can you please format your question? Its hard to read

Comment: What did you do so far?

Comment: Hint: `std::getline`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate through your file until the end is reached as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string line;

    std::ifstream arq("/tmp/blah");

    if (arq.is_open()){

        while (!arq.eof()) {

            std::getline(arq, line);

            std::cout << line << std::endl; // prints the line you've just read
        }
    }
}
```

The values can be retrieved from the string by tokenizing it [just like in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c), and then converted to double as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754011/c-string-to-double-conversion).