# how to get all decimal number from string in c++

Tags: c++, string, decimal

I'm trying to get value (all decimal number) from a text in c++. But I have a problem and I couldn't solve it

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream infile("C:\\thefile.txt");
    float a, b;
    while (infile >> a >> b)
    {
        // process pair (a,b)
    }

    std::cout << a << " " << b;

}
```

thefile.txt:

```
34.123456789 77.987654321
```

When I run the above code,

```
a = 34.1235 
b = 77.9877
```

but I want

```
a = 34.123456789 
b = 77.987654321
```

what should I do?

EDIT: I don't want to print out of a and b. I just want they get the exact values.net

Comment: Does your computer have enough precision in a `float` to do that? Are you sure?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I am not sure anything. I don't want to print a and b. I just want a and b get the all values. If they already get all values and if it appear in a short way because of printing, it's okay. can you tell me ?

Comment: @NathanOliver I accepted your small answer. thank you bro

Comment: @NathanOliver also which type should I use? double or float?

Comment: for     float a, b;

Comment: You can check the real value of the variable using a *debugger*. But for printing, the duplicate answers it well.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen thank you. also float a,b; is correct? or should I use double?

Comment: @NathanOliver Really? I thought a IEEE 754 single-precision float only guaranteed six-ish decimal significant figures (barring looser constraints on powers of two)

Comment: What is "cout.net"?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You're correct.  Not sure what I was thinking.  They'd need a double for full precision.

Comment: @NathanOliver Nearly the weekend....

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit you made me confuse...

Comment: @NathanOliver you made me confuse...

Comment: @Yksisarvinen you made me confuse...

Comment: @baybaybay Your comment (written three times!) does not add anything to the discussion.

Answer (score 5):

You can't.

A [`float`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) can only give you six (ish) decimal *significant figures*. The values in your file, after conversion from string, cannot be held in a `float`.

First, you need to switch to [`double`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), otherwise you won't even have a variable with the full numerical value.

Then, for output, be careful to [specify the precision you want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554063/how-do-i-print-a-double-value-with-full-precision-using-cout).

Please remain aware of the foibles of floating-point, and consider sticking with strings, depending on what you're doing with this data.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main things i see in your code.

1. **float** precision is not enough for you data you need **double** data type.
2. you need to set proper cout precision to get your desired output.

This code will work for you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream infile("newfile.txt");
    double a, b;
    std::cout.precision(11);
    while (infile >> a >> b)
    {
        // process pair (a,b)
    }

    std::cout << a << " " << b;
}
```

Comment: this doesn't show all value when I print out. But I don't want to show, I just want they get the exact values. Do they get the exact values if I use double?

Comment: @baybaybay Try it and find out?

Answer (score 0):

you should read your inputs into a string and then convert them into double (depending on enough precision in float on your computer). you can directly display strings. A possible answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4754486/11548219).

```
string word;  
openfile >> word;
double lol = atof(word.c_str());
```

Comment: Why do this yourself when IOStreams will do it for you? In code that the OP's written?

Comment: @ShafiqaIqbal I didn't get all what you said