# Convert string with 6 digits before decimal to Double

Tags: string, double, precision

I have a string with the value `788597.31` and I am converting this value to double but when I print the variable only 788597 is displayed. I have used std::stod(string) and even stringstream but everytime I get the same previous value. Can anybody help me with this?
I want to store this string value in a double varaible.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string s="788597.31";
  double d=stod(s);
  cout<<d<<" ";
  stringstream g;
  double a; 
  g<<s; g>>a;
  cout<<a;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code with us?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ string to double conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754011/c-string-to-double-conversion)

Comment: Check whether the problem is in the string parsing or the output.

Comment: I have shared the code . pls check it now

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in how you are printing your result, not in the string parsing. This program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << 788597.31 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

also prints 788597.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << setprecision(10) << 788597.31 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

prints 788597.31

If you want to see more than the default 6 significant digits your program needs to say so.

Comment: You can check yourself by using setprecision.

Comment: Please you run my code and show me. First you need to convert the string to double and then print it.

Comment: @Sarthak I have shown you how to get more than 6 significant digits in your output. Fix that in your program and carry on from there.