# ostringstream gives me Implicit instantiation error

Tags: c++, string

I'm trying the elegant solution provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/332132/768472) but no matter what I try, I cannot get passed the error `Implicit instantiation of undefined template` for this line:

`std::ostringstream strs;`

What I need to do? I've included the following, which I'm sure is overkill. As a second question it seems hard to track down what exactly needs to be included for ostringstream:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iosfwd>
#include <ios>
```

Comment: I see the link you have provided and if your intention is to change a double to string and you have C++11 support, just use `std::to_string(double)`.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

`stringstream` classes are defined in `sstream` header, so write

```
#include <sstream>
```

and all will be fine.

Comment: thanks, it worked, I'm curious how I could find this out easily myself. I looked it up and it doesn't say anything about this particular header: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/ostringstream/. My compiler (Xcode) says it is declared in `iosfwd`

Comment: @SebbyJohanns `<iosfwd>` only provides forward *declarations* for i/o classes. You need to `#include` the correct header in your cpp file for the *definition*. `<iosfwd>` is present for use in headers where you do not need the full class definition. This helps in reducing compilation times.

Comment: thanks. i'd still like to know the best way to actually find out what headers include the full definitions of things like this. i was on quite a goose chase to track it down before posing here, and it seems like it should be an elementary task to look up. where would I do that? @indeterminatelysequenced

Comment: @SebbyJohanns [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/a7tkse1h.aspx) is the most reliable source I have found online. (other than the standard drafts).

Comment: @SebbyJohanns I think one clue is in the URL of the link you posted. Another is that on that page <sstream> is highlighted in the top left menu.

Comment: @SebbyJohanns Use a [*better reference*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream).

Comment: @indeterminatelysequenced *"msdn is the most reliable source I have found online"* - I wouldn't trust them so much regarding information about the C++ standard either (they made errors and inaccuracies before, though not neccessarily in this case). *cppreference.com* is still the most reliable source, even if still incomplete in certain parts.