# what's concise C++ idiom for conversion from int|double to string?

Tags: c++

Looking through related Q&A's, it seems that best C++ practice for conversion to string is

```
ostringstream stringStream;
stringStream << input_value;        // let's say, input_value is a double
output_string = stringStream.str();
```

Is there any way to achieve the same in less than three lines of clean C++?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590381/easiest-way-to-convert-int-to-string-in-c and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332111/how-do-i-convert-a-double-into-a-string-in-c

Comment: Put the above three lines in a function, then it'll only take one line.

Comment: Thanks for the many useful answers! Seems I am allowed to accept only one, that will forcibly be an arbitrary choice, sorry.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using the [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) family of functions:

```
std::string s = std::to_string(3.1416);
```

If you don't have the required C++11, another option is [`boost::lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html).

```
std::string s = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(3.1416);
```

Answer (score 10):

Yes, with [std::to_string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string):

```
output_string = std::to_string(input_value);
```

(For C++03, look into `boost::lexical_cast`).

Comment: Notice that this is a `C++11` feature

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have C++11, you can use something like:

```
boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(input_value);
```

(it's easy enough to write your own to_string if you don't want Boost though - you're really just wrapping your existing code in a function).

If you *do* have C++11, stick with the `std::to_string` Jesse Good & juanchopanza already mentioned.

Comment: boost is not part of the standard C++. And wrapping everything in a function hiding everything can always be done by anyone, but... it doesn't explain anything

Comment: `to_string` and `lexical_cast` are functions - what's the difference?

Comment: to_string and std::stringstream are part of the C++ standard.  Boost is not. And if we admit to take elsewhere delivered functions, we  are playing a different game.

Answer (score 0):

Both are one-liners in C++ 11:

```
std::string s1 = std::to_string(42);
```

and

```
std::string s2 = std::to_string(42.0);
```