# using static_cast<datatype> to convert float to string c++

Tags: c++, casting, static-cast

so this is my first "test" using static_cast, i have never done so, so please bear with me (i am very new to c++, stated 3 days ago)

```
// ConsoleApplication3.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "string"


int main()
{
    float value = 2.5f;
    int temp;
    std::cout << value;
    std::cout << static_cast<std::string>(value) ;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

it gives an error saying

> error C2440: 'static_cast' : cannot convert from 'float' to
>   'std::string'
>
> IntelliSense: no suitable constructor exists to convert from "float"
>   to "std::basic_string,
>   std::allocator>"

am I missing something?

Comment: Can't do that. `std::to_string` or `std::sprintf(buf, "%f", value)` or `std::stof`

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c36yw7x9.aspx, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_cast

Comment: side note: your includes do not look good: "system" includes should be included with `#include <something>`, not `"`. Also, you are not using stdafx and if you are just learning C++, I suggest you forget it - but it's my opinable opinion.

Answer (score 4):

`static_cast` is used to safely convert convertable types between each other, meaning types that either share the same base class or types that define conversion operators between each other. Although `std::string` may define a constructor that takes in a `float` (not sure) it is not cast-able from `float`.

Comment: +1.  Perhaps also worth mentioning `boost::lexical_cast<>` as an alternative to achieve what they think they need to achieve :)

Answer (score 2):

`static_cast` can't be used in this way.  `static_cast` is used to *cast* -- in other words, pretend (in a way) that the thing passed in is actually something else.  What you need to do is *convert*.

You don't need to convert a `float` to `cout` it -- just:

```
std::cout << value;
```

If you do need to convert, then there are many options:

1. [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) (C++11)
2. [`std::stringsgtream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream)
3. [`boost::lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html)

Are just a few.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve is not casting, but converting a float to a string. There are several ways to do this.

This explains static_cast pretty well: [Regular cast vs. static_cast vs. dynamic_cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002/regular-cast-vs-static-cast-vs-dynamic-cast)

This explains how to transform a real number to a string: [How do I convert a double into a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332111/how-do-i-convert-a-double-into-a-string-in-c)

And this is an answer everyone should read about various casts in c++: [When should static_cast, dynamic_cast, const_cast and reinterpret_cast be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used)

Answer (score 1):

[`static_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) is used to convert from one type to other convertible type. A conversion from `float` to `std::string` is not defined.

However, the way to obtain a string representation of a value is to call the function [`std::to_string()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string):

```
int main()
{
    float val = 10.0f;

    std::string str = std::to_string( val );
}
```

But output streams are dessigned to work with non-string types too. So simply put the float into the stream:

```
std::cout << val;
```

> 10.0