# Displaying output shell stream (cout or printf) to Textview widget (GTK+ 3) in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, user-interface, gtk

I would like to use textview widget to display outputs throughout my program, there are bunch of cout and printf where I display particular information, now I would like to use a GUI in GTK+ to display the outputs that I see on command shell.

I read somewhere I need to use GIOchannel and in other places, somewhere else they just suggested to write to gtk_text_buffer_insert(), the problem is the latter function takes char pointer, and I display doubles and floats. Casting doesn't work and it shouldn't work really.

How do I do this?

Comment: There is a way to take a double and float and represent them as char arrays. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332111/how-do-i-convert-a-double-into-a-string-in-c. From there just pass the array variable as the pointer argument for the guy method.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a stream buffer writing to your widget. You'd derive a class from `std::streambuf` send character strings to whatever widget function and use an `std::ostream` initialised with this stream buffer. You can replace `std::cout`'s stream buffer (using `std::cout.rdbuf(&sbuf)`) if you can't pass a stream to functions where it is used. You'll need to get replace your `printf()`s, though, if you also want these output to go to your widget.