# C++ Question mark output

Tags: c++, string, binary, output

I have a simple program that converts decimal numbers to binary numbers. No errors come up when I run the program but I do get a single question mark. I should get a set of values like "00101" I am trying to use a function that returns a string as well. Here is my code,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string>

string convert(int num)
{
    string binary;
    int remainder;

    while (num !=0 )
    {
        remainder = num % 2;
        num = num / 2;
        binary = remainder;
    }
    return binary;
}

int main()
{
   int number;
   string binaryNum;
   cout << "Enter a Number:";
   cin >> number;

   binaryNum = convert(number);
   cout << "This is your number in binary form:" << binaryNum << endl;

   system("pause");
}
```

Any ideas?
Thanks for the help

Comment: code `return binary;` in `while` will return on first loop.   why you doing that ?

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to figure out if that is where the issue was. I have tried to remove it but I get the same problem.

Comment: You are trying to assign integer value into a string without converting it to a string. This is the main issue. I believe you can fix other logical errors in your code after fixing it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems with this code.  First, you are assigning the string `binary` using the `=` sign on the line `binary = remainder`.  What you probably meant to write was `binary += remainder`, to append the remainder to the string.

The second problem is also on that line.  Both `string::operator=` and `string::operator+=` have overloads that take a char.  Those overloads are called, when you pass in an int.  So the string is being set to the character whose ascii value is 0 or 1, thus the question mark character, which is not what you are looking for.  You can use `std::to_string` to easily convert your `int` into a string.  Or if you need any level of control over the formatting, you can use `std::ostringstream` as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332111/how-do-i-convert-a-double-into-a-string-in-c).

In other words, change `binary = remainder;` to `binary += std::to_string(remainder)`.

Third problem: There is a return statement inside the `while` loop.  The function will return after one iteration of the loop, no matter how large `num` is.  Remove that return statement, so there is only the one at the very end of the `convert` function.

Answer (score -1):

There is a basic problem with your code.
The while loop will iterate only once as you are returning a value.
You should concatenate binaryValue every time with remainder, and return it outside loop.
And I haven't checked the logic so do check it.