# Will this code run correctly on big endian and little endian systems?

Tags: c++, endianness

I'm writing code for a platform with constrained access to the standard C++ library and I am trying to push an array of doubles through an interface which will only accept an array of uint8.   I saw this stack overflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339150/extracting-individual-digits-from-a-float)

which shows a way of converting a double precision value to an int array.   here's my code.  (note that index 1 and index 9 are the decimal and delimiter respectively.  also the values are always between 0.0 and 1.0)

```
void Instrument::ConvertDoubleToUInt8Array(double a_dValue, int *a_dValueArray)
{

    a_dValueArray[0] = (int(a_dValue)%10);
    a_dValueArray[1] = 10;
    a_dValueArray[2] = (int(a_dValue*10)%10);
    a_dValueArray[3] = (int(a_dValue*100)%10);
    a_dValueArray[4] = (int(a_dValue*1000)%10);
    a_dValueArray[5] = (int(a_dValue*10000)%10);
    a_dValueArray[6] = (int(a_dValue*100000)%10);
    a_dValueArray[7] = (int(a_dValue*1000000)%10);
    a_dValueArray[8] = (int(a_dValue*10000000)%10);
    a_dValueArray[9] = 11;
}
```

my question is will this code run correctly on both big endian and little endian systems.  I cannot see why it wouldn't but I'm not very experienced in this area

Comment: Issues of endianness are only relevant if you're directly manipulating individual bytes of some larger type.

Comment: The code, as shown, does not depend on endianness.

Comment: Thanks for both responses