# Inline ostringstream macro reloaded

Tags: c++, visual-c++, macros, ostringstream

Referring to [C++ format macro / inline ostringstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303562/c-format-macro-inline-ostringstream)

The question there was for a macro that allows inline concatenation of objects to create a string, iostream-style.

The answer was:

```
#define SSTR( x ) dynamic_cast< std::ostringstream & >( \
        ( std::ostringstream().seekp( 0, std::ios_base::cur ) << x ) \
    ).str()
```

Usage (for example):

```
throw std::runtime_error(
        SSTR( "FooBar error: Value " << x << " exceeds " << y )
);
```

That works beautifully - with GCC. It compiles and runs under Visual C++ 2005, too. But with the latter, all uses of the macro result in empty strings, and I am quite dumbfounded as to why, and how to fix it...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't have access to a MSVC compiler to test against.

In my past experiences with microsoft's tools, it seems like microsoft treats language definitions and standards as little more than a rough guide.  (I've lost lots of time on projects only to discover microsoft broke tradition with something as basic as C99.)

Given this regrettably situation, I suggest you experiment with a series of trivial programs.  Things like:

```
std::ostringstream() o;
o.seekp( 0, std::ios_base::cur ) << "foo";
cout << "Test1:  " << o << endl;
```

Or perhaps:

```
std::ostringstream() o;
cout << "Test2:  " << typeid(o).name() << endl;
cout << "Test3:  " << typeid(o.seekp( 0, std::ios_base::cur )).name() << endl;
```

Try to see at what point things stop working.  Then work around the problem from there.

Comment: seekp() was the culprit. Not sure what MSVC++ does differently with that, but replacing

    ostringstream().seekp( 0, ios_base::cur )

with

    ostringstream() << std::dec

(as cadabra suggested) works for MSVC++.

I left a note on the original question so others don't get caught by it.