# Can I pass C++ strings into a method in the style of a stream?

Tags: c++, string, stringstream

I'd like to do this:

```
MyClass mc = MyClass("Some string" << anotherString);
```

Thanks for your answers, I have decided to re-write this question based on what you've told me, as it's gotten a little messy. Eventually, I read [C++ format macro / inline ostringstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303562/c-format-macro-inline-ostringstream), and decided to use a macro, as it's not really possible to do this using a constructor. Some answers my no longer be relevant.

Now, what I can actually, do is:

```
MY_CLASS("Some string" << anotherString << " more string!");
```

Using this macro:

```
#include <sstream>

#define MY_CLASS(stream) \
MyClass( ( dynamic_cast<std::ostringstream &> ( \
    std::ostringstream() . seekp( 0, std::ios_base::cur ) << stream ) \
) . str() )
```

Where the MyClass constructor takes a string:

```
MyClass::MyClass(string s) { /* ... */ }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303562/303675#303675) question for some hints as to what will be required to get the behavior you want.

This sort of thing seems to a bit difficult.

Answer (score 4):

redesign your solution. if your c-tor needed string it should accept string.
also in this and similar cases will better if your constructor will accept const reference.

```
no matching function for call to ‘MyClass(std::basic_ostream <..>&)
```

error happened because operator<< defined for and returns std::basic_ostream not std::stringstream object. ofcourse you could use

```
dynamic_cast< const std::stringstream& >( s << "hello" << "world" )
```

but your team lead could fire you for this code:)

**BTW:**

```
MyClass mc = MyClass("Some string" << anotherString);
```

could be rewriten as

```
MyClass mc("Some string" << anotherString);
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the shorthand init.

Comment: use const std::string& you will avoid unnecessary copying

Answer (score 2):

Your compile error looks like have included

```
<iosfwd>
```

in your class's header file, but you haven't included

```
<sstream>
```

in the cxx file.

Comment: This isn't going to help since "Some string" << anotherString doesn't create a string.

Comment: Thanks, this post was relevant before I restructured the question - and helped it a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The << operator returns an ostream &, not a streamstream &, so you'd have to do a dynamic cast:

```
MyClass::MyClass(ostream &stream)
{
    string myString = dynamic_cast<stringstream &>(stream.str());
}

stringstream s;
MyClass *mc = new MyClass(s << "Some string" << anotherString);
```

But really that's a terrible thing to do.  Try something like this:

```
class Streamer
{
stringstream stream;
public:
    template <class T>
    Streamer &operator <<(const T &object) { stream << object; return *this;}
    operator string() { return stream.str(); }
};    

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(const string &s) : MyString(s) {}
    string MyString;
};

int main()
{
    MyClass myClass(Streamer() << "something" << "world");
    cout << myClass.MyString;
}
```

Comment: Unless, as I did, you force a stringstream to be constructed.

Comment: Yes, I think that's the most sensible approach. Of coutrse, he probably doesn't need to create the MyClass instance with new, either.

Comment: Is this more elegant than using a macro?

Comment: Good point, I mean elegant as in: Implementation is clearer / easier.

Comment: Clearer would just be to pass in a string in the first place:  MyClass myClass(string("something") + "other thing");