# How to store a concatenation of ints and characters in a char*?

Tags: c++, c, string

I have some integers, let's say `one` `two` and `three`.  I wish to create a string such as

```
char* example = "There are " + one + " bottles of water on " + 
    two + " shelves in room number " + three + "\n".`
```

This doesn't work in C/C++.  How can I store that type of value in a char*?

Comment: That's why I told you beforehand that they were integers.  Would you rather I wrote "int one = 3; int two = 6; int three = 1;"?

Comment: Yes.  Then we'd know that they are ints and not strings.

Comment: If you didn't tag this "C++" by accident, I should point out that in C++ it's almost always better to work with `string`s instead of `char*`s.

Comment: Alsso, there's no such language named C/C++.  They are seperate languages, and the method you select depends on which language you're working in.  So pick one.

Comment: @John Dibling - `int` is implicit in question title, by process of elimination...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++ isn't VB.  But you have numerous options.

### stringstream:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

stringstream ss;
ss<< "There are " << one << " bottles of water on " << two << " shelves in room number " << three;
string s = ss.str();
```

### boost/format:

```
#include <boost/format.hpp>
#include <string>

string s = (boost::format("There are %1% bottles on %2% shelves in room number %3%")%one%two%three).str();
```

### old-school (hacky, unsafe, bad, dont do it)

```
char buffer[1024] = {};
sprintf(buffer, "There are %d bottles on %d shelves in room number %d", one, two, three);
```

Comment: You can also `lexical_cast` the numbers and concatenate.

Answer (score 7):

In C there's more than one way to do it, depending how you would like to allocate the memory[*]. For the straightforward option of allocating it from the heap:

```
len = snprintf(0, 0, "%d bottles, %d shelves, room %d\n", one, two, three);
char *result = malloc(len+1);
if (result == 0) { /* handle error */ }
snprintf(result, len+1, "%d bottles, %d shelves, room %d\n", one, two, three);

/* some time later */
free(result);
```

Beware non-standard implementations of `snprintf`, that don't return the length when the buffer is exceeded. Check your documentation.

In C++, `snprintf` is not in the standard, and even where it is available, the above code would need to cast the result of malloc[**]. C++ adds the option of using stringstreams:

```
std::stringsteam r;
r << one << " bottles, " << two << " shelves, room " << three << "\n";
std::string result = r.str();

// if you absolutely need a char*, use result.c_str(), but don't forget that
// the pointer becomes invalid when the string, "result" ceases to exist.
```

This saves messing with buffer lengths, makes resource management easier, and avoids the risk with `printf` and friends that you could pass an argument of the wrong type for the format specifier. It's usually the preferred option.

It is however less flexible in some circumstances: the format is hard-wired into the code rather than contained in a format string, so it's harder to make the text configurable. It can also be a bit harder to read, for instance it's not at all uncommon to leave out a space character on the first version of any such line of code. But if you want to use the `snprintf` approach in C++, and `snprintf` is available in your implementation, then you can take advantage of C++'s easier memory management as follows:

```
len = std::snprintf(0, 0, "%d bottles, %d shelves, room %d\n", one, two, three);
std::vector<char> r(len+1);
std::snprintf(&r[0], r.size(), "%d bottles, %d shelves, room %d\n", one, two, three);

char *result = &r[0];
// again, "result" is only valid as long as "r" is in scope
```

[*] Note that you cannot "store" a string in a `char*`, because a `char*` is just a pointer. You can store a pointer to a string in a `char*`, but the string itself is a completely separate thing.

[**] because C and C++ ARE DIFFERENT LANGUAGES!

Answer (score 1):

`sprintf` is an option (as Ólafur wrote), but deprecated. Use `snprintf` when you can - sprintf can lead to buffer overruns and cause awful crashes and bugs if you're not very careful with the size of your buffer and inputs.

```
char output[256];
snprintf(output, sizeof(output), "There are %d bottles of water on %d shelves 
    in room number %d\n", one, two, three);
```

Comment: "sprintf is good"  yeah, ok.  How did you come up with the magic number `256`?  Is it big enough?  It it wasteful?  How can you be sure that `one`, `two` and `three` are `ints`?  If somee maint programmer comes along and changes one of the types are you prepared to explode?

Comment: `snprintf` also deprecated in C++

Comment: @Steve: I don't believe it is formally deprecated (and neither is `sprintf`). People prefer not to use it.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <sstream>

std::stringstream strVal;

strVal << std::string("There are ") << one << std::string(" bottles of water on ") << 
    two << std::string(" shelves in room number ") << three << std::endl;

std::string copyStr(strVal.str());
const char * example = copyStr.c_str();
```

Comment: I think you need to put that in to a `string` and take the `c_str()`

Comment: @John - Yes, or preferably forget the `char*` altogether

Comment: @Steve:  But now you put it in to a temporary that has evaporated after the `;`

Comment: @John, yes I forgot the `strdup` call. Thanks for the code review.

Comment: May I ask what are those temporary strings for? I mean the ones constructed from the string literals.

Comment: @Maciej - clarification for OP - not necessary to make it work

Answer (score 0):

I like the stringstream approach, but I use a class to simplify its usage. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303562/c-format-macro-inline-ostringstream/303716#303716) to another SO question for more details:

```
string myString = MakeString() << "There are " << one << " 
      bottles of water on " << two << " shelves in room number " << three;

char * example = myString.c_str(); // if you really need a char *
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
template <typename T> std::string toStr(const T& something) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << something;
    return ss.str();
}
...
std::string example = "There are " + toStr(one) + " bottles of water on " + 
                toStr(two) + " shelves in room number " + toStr(three) + "\n";
```