# How does qDebug() print enum values?

Tags: qt

We have a simple piece of code in our application:

```
void tAccessPoint::OnStateChanged(QAbstractSocket::SocketState state)
{
    qDebug() << m_ID << " " << state;
```

For reasons that aren't important here I was attempting to replace the use of qDebug so I used the code from this post [C++ format macro / inline ostringstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303562/c-format-macro-inline-ostringstream). But I was surprised to find that when I do this **state** no longer appears as a text value but rather as a numeric value. qDebug() seems to know what the name of the enum value is rather than just the value. How does it do this, and can I do the same in my code?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is no moc magic here, QtNetwork defines explicitly the operator in network/socket/qabstractsocket.h:

```
QDebug operator<<(QDebug debug, QAbstractSocket::SocketState state) {
    switch (state) {
    case QAbstractSocket::UnconnectedState:
        debug << "QAbstractSocket::UnconnectedState";
        break;
    case QAbstractSocket::HostLookupState:
        debug << "QAbstractSocket::HostLookupState";
        break;
    case QAbstractSocket::ConnectingState:
        debug << "QAbstractSocket::ConnectingState";
        break;
    case QAbstractSocket::ConnectedState:
        debug << "QAbstractSocket::ConnectedState";
        break;
    case QAbstractSocket::BoundState:
        debug << "QAbstractSocket::BoundState";
        break;
    ...
    return debug;
}
```

But you can use `QDebug` to send the data to a `QString` inside your function:

```
 QString output;
 QDebug(&output) << ...
```

Answer (score 10):

Maybe this enum to QString convert can be useful :

```
const QMetaObject & mo = QAbstractSocket::staticMetaObject;
QMetaEnum me = mo.enumerator(mo.indexOfEnumerator("SocketState"));
QString test(me.valueToKey(QAbstractSocket::UnconnectedState));
```

Comment: This looks like a very useful technique. Unfortunately, not all enums are registered with moc. For example, QProcess::ProcessError is just an ordinary C++ enum, so no support for converting it to a name :(